# Not able to add a line of text after pattern using sed in OSX

Tags: bash, macos, sed, terminal, zsh

I'm trying to add a line in a file `afile.xyz` using my script. This is what I've done so far using sed:

```
n="$(grep ".method" "$m" | grep "onCreate(Landroid/os/Bundle;)V")"

sed -i '' -e '/$n/ a\
"test", /Users/username/Documents/afile.xyz
```

I'm getting the error:

```
"onCreate\(\Landroid\/ ...": bad flag in substitute command: 'g'
```

How do I solve this? Please do help. Thanks.

Edit: Content of n

```
method protected onCreate(Landroid/os/Bundle;)V
```

Comment: show what's the content of `n` and also fix the unbalanced `'` (single quotes)

Comment: I have updated the post sir. Please help.

Comment: There are quite some inconsistencies in your question. With `'/$n/ ...'` (note the single quotes) you shouldn't get an error. Also, the value of `$n` cannot start with `method`, as you obtained it by searching for `.method`.

Answer (score 0):

2 problems:

1. because the sed body is in single quotes, the variable `$n` will *not* be expanded,
2. the regular expression in `$n` contains the `/` dilimiters.

Try this:

```sh
n=$(...)
nn=${n//\//\\/}    # escape all slashes

sed -i '' '/'"${nn}"'/ a ...
```

The single-quoted sed body is interrupted to append the double quoted shell variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a different delimiter for the RE:

```
sed -i '' -e "\#$n# a\\
\"test\"" /Users/username/Documents/afile.xyz
```